# SessionNotCreatedException Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser startup failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, appium

Server is on through command line
device is connected and listed in adb devices
using
appium 2.0
java client 8.3.0 ,
selenium support 4.8.3

Why i am getting that error
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

also  i am not getting console on appium server all console i am reading in IDE

I tried many methods i aded guava library, changed mobile device , tried on virtual device, kill server  every time i am getting same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.